# ImageButton wont show on fragment added to a layout

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, fragment, imagebutton

I have a map activity inside a layout so whenever I add an `ImageButton, it will display in the design editor but when I run on mobile
 it does not show anything or else it shows a very small dot.

But I add the same image to a different layout without any fragment, the
image will show no problem so I think it is to do with fragment any
idea, please thank you

here my code but it should show without define it any way

```
ImageButton im=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imb);
```

but floating button and normal button works no problem

here is my activiy fragment

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
```

that is all i have in the activity
 and all i can see on the list of override methode is this one

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
ImageButton im=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imb);
```

with

```
ImageButton im=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imb);
```

In which `view` is the `fragment view` which you are inflating when you start your fragment.

Your `view` is coming from a line of code that looks like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for quick response so what i did is to declare Inflater inflater; then i called View view ... do i do it right? and i do not know what that container to be replaced with thanks

Comment: You don't need to declare(create) another `Inflater inflater`, because the `inflater` object is used from arguments privides by the method. For sure you have something like this in your fragment. `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {` About this `inflater` i'm talking about.

Comment: ok i removed Inflater now the inflater is red and i do not see any of this View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  inside the code so what i did is i created mapactivity from android studio then i added relative layout and i put the map fragment inside that layout im a bigginer not advance so do not know much i hope you advice me in details thank you

Comment: thanks i edited my codes that is all i have from activity all other rating bar floating button and normal button works but imagebutton and image view wont work yeas it display on android studio but wont on mobile testing thank you

Comment: You need to override in your activity the `onCreateView()` method and use that code there. If you use Android Studio, press `ALT+Insert` -> Override methods and choose the right one.

Comment: Alex Mamo thank you i have added the overriding methods to my code i edited look last part please but still nothink like you mentioned. thank you, i may use floating button instead imagebutton wont work thank you